# How to use setFindTimeout in intern.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, intern

How often do I need to set the setFindTimeout for my functional test?

When I execute the setFindTimeout,sometimes I need to put it in other test cases to change the findBy* method timeout.

-----------------Edit------------------------

What happen if I have multiple suite on different file.
For example I have start.js and admin.js
Is it your answer still valid for this case?

start.js

```
'use strict';
define([
  'intern!object',
  'intern/chai!assert',
  'intern/dojo/node!fs'
], (registerSuite, assert, fs) => {
  registerSuite(() => {
    let testData;
    let timeout;
    let testCases;
    testCases = {
      name: 'Project Feature Test',

      'Log into project': function() {

        this.timeout = 60000 * 5;

        return this.remote

          .get(testData['site'])
          .findByXpath('//a[@href="/saml-redirect"]').click().end()
          .findById('userName').type(testData['username']).end()
          .findById('password').type(testData['password']).end()
          .findById('loginButton').click().end();
      },
    };

    return testCases;
  });
});
```

admin.js

```
'use strict';

define([
  'intern!object',
  'intern/chai!assert',
  'intern/dojo/node!fs'
], (
  registerSuite,
  assert,
  fs
) => {
  registerSuite(() => {

    testCases = {
      name: 'Test Administration Page',

      'Check User Functions': function() {
        this.timeout = timeout * 3;
        return this.remote
          .sleep(3000)
          .findByClassName('admin-button').click().end()  //goto admin page
      }
    };
    return testCases;
  });
});
```

Comment: Please add more context to the question. May be some code. Question doesn't seem to be very clear.

Answer (score 0):

`setFindTimeout` sets the `findBy` timeout for a test session. Once you set it, the new timeout value persists through all the remaining tests in that session, or until it's changed by another call to `setFindTimeout`.

Comment: The find timeout is relative to the session, not to an individual test suite. If it's set in one suite, it will persist for that session through all other suites until testing ends. You don't seem to be calling `setFindTimeout` anywhere in your code, though.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, if you cannot control which file will run first, which will run after, then it's better to set in both files.
I often set it once in `before` of the top parent suite